# After upgrading to Windows10, Vim does not fully function

Tags: vim, windows-10

I had installed Vim 7.4 under Windows 7, and worked great.
Then I upgraded to Windows 10, and now, I lost the VIM functionality, but the basic VI functionality is still there.

Is there some configuration that I need to do to fully work with Windows 10?

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall, but I am left with the same issue.

When I "echo $VIMRUMTIME"
I get "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\Vim74\gvim.exe"
but I thought it was the folder, not the file.

Where is this set?

Comment: is the vimrc config correctly loaded?

Comment: I tried to load _vimrc and I get errors: that $VIMRUNTIME is as above, hence that certain files cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out....

I had set "VIM" equal to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" as a system environment variable, thus, missing up everything, thereafter.

Which is strange that $VIMRUNTIME would be dependent upon $VIM, but there you go.

que sera sera